# Auxiliary Constructor with Different Parameters

Tags: scala, constructor

Is there a way to define auxiliary constructor using completely different set of parameters than primary constructor?

Example - let's have a Customer class:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

case class Customer( id : Int, revenue : Double) {
  
  //auxiliary constructor 
  def this(r : Row) = {
    this(r.getAs[Int]("CustomerId"), r.getAs[Double]("InvoiceTotal"))
  }
}
```

While the definition above compiles just fine, I'm not able to call the alternate constructor from the code. Example below causes compilation error `not enough arguments for method apply: (id, revenue)...`.

```
val newCustomer = customer(currentRow)
```

All examples I've found here on SO or other pages (e.g. [geeks for geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scala-constructors/)) always show auxiliary constructors with paramters that are super-set of default primary constructor parameters. How could I build constructors that would fit the scenario from my example above?

Comment: Hint: read the error message. Does it *actually* say that you are "not able to call the alternate constructor from the code", as you claim? In fact, does it say anything about constructors *at all*? Hint #2: Look up how to invoke a constructor.

Comment: Instead of a auxiliary constructor which is not very common, you can add an auxiliary factory on the companion object. - btw, if you ask me, you shouldn't be using a distributed engine if you do not even understand how case classes work.

Comment: @<Luis Miguel Mejia Suarez> care to explain further? Especially regarding answers below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you define your auxiliary constructor is fine.  Parameters of an auxiliary constructor don't have to overlap with (or be a subset of) the primary constructor's.

However, to instantiate your case class via an auxiliary constructor, you'll need to use `new` (as if it were an ordinary class), or else the default `apply` would instantiate via the primary constructor.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

case class Customer(id: Int, revenue: Double) {  
  def this(r: Row) =
    this(r.getAs[Int]("CustomerId"), r.getAs[Double]("InvoiceTotal"))
}

val df = Array((1, 1000.0), (2, 2000.0)).toDF("CustomerId", "InvoiceTotal")

df.map(row => new Customer(row)).printSchema
// root
//  |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
//  |-- revenue: double (nullable = false)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Customer` is a case class, which means that the simplified constructor `Customer(currentRow)` is trying to invoke this code in the companion object...

```
object Customer {
  def apply(id:Int, revenue:Double):Customer = new Customer(id, revenue)
}
```

...which is bypassing the auxiliary constructor.

Try `new Customer(currentRow)` and see if that works for you.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Using object works fine (I had it in my project until finding answer from Leo C), but I hoped to keep entire class behavior within its core definition if possible. That's why flagging Leo C's response for answer.

Comment: Thank you for further explanation - I see what you meant now and have been misled by my own work-around. Still, Leo's answer provides more understandable explanation and example, thus please let me keep his as the accepted version.